# Selecionar um checkbox e não ordenar o dataTables

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Estou usando o [dataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) e em uma das colunas eu coloquei um `input:checkbox` para o usuário poder marcar todas colunas ou desmarcar, lembrando que nas colunas eu tenho como fazer a ordenação, e nessa coluna também tenho isso, pois preciso ter para saber quais itens já estão ou não marcados. Até ai tudo funcionando.

O que não estou sabendo como fazer é que, quando o usuário clica no `checkbox` não faça a ordenação, somente fazer essa ordenação quando clicar na coluna em si. Hoje, quando ele clica para marcar ou desmarcar já faz a ordenação, e isso que não pode acontecer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O trecho que crio de html é o seguinte:

```
<table id="datatables">
    <thead>
        <th>
            <tr>Tema</tr>
            <tr>Monitoramento</tr>
            <tr><input type="checkbox"></tr>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Alimentos</td>
            <td>monitoramento alimentos 2</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alimentos</td>
            <td>monitoramento alimentos 3</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: seria possível você por favor postar algum trecho do seu código html da datatables?

Comment: Já faço a edição da pergunta, mas já comentando que é um html de uma tabela comum.

Answer (score 2):

Marcelo, imagino que o problema aqui é que o evento `click` se propaga ao elemento pai do `input`, ao qual o dataTables amarra um event listener para fazer o re-sort. Assim acho que o importate aqui é usar o [**.stopPropagation()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation)

```
$('table th input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/5LPnu/)

Note que a sua sintaxe da table está incorrecta. O descendente de `<thead>` é `<tr>` e depois `<th>` não o contrário.

---

**Edit:**

No caso de browsers antingos teste assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datatables').dataTable();
    $('table th input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : event.returnValue = false;
    });
});
```

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8eBtw/)

Comment: Só tem um problema ao usar o stopPropagation(), ele roda somente no IE9, saberia me dizer se tem algo para funcionar nos inferiores, pois infelizmente ainda tem muito usuário e cliente com esses navegadores antigos. Ainda assim muito obrigado

Comment: @MarceloDiniz, editei a resposta com um acrescento. Testei no IE8 e funcionou bem

Comment: Aqui onde estou não tenho nenhum IE para testar, mas imagino que funcione como você disse. Não sei, mas vi esse link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045162/event-returnvalue-is-deprecated-please-use-the-standard-event-preventdefault que diz que retornvalue esta deprecated. Mais para constar. Valew

Comment: @MarceloDiniz, dê uma olhada à resposta do Rafael. Se o plugin já suporta parece-me a melhor maneira.

Comment: coloquei um comentário explicando o pq não pode ser. Mas ainda assim valew.

Answer (score 2):

O próprio datatables tem solução para isso, usando as definições de coluna.

eu faço assim:

```
     "aoColumnDefs": [
  { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 7 ] },
```

Isso tem que ser feito no javascript que chama o datatables.

link para documentação do parametro. http://www.datatables.net/ref#bSearchable

Comment: Então, eu até uso esse parametro em algumas tabelas minhas, mas como eu disse, nessa coluna eu preciso do ordenação para saber quais itens estão ou não marcados.

Comment: Olá Marcelo, desculpe não ter levado em consideração que você ainda precisava ordenar a coluna. Segundo este link http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11872/is-it-possible-to-sort-only-by-clicking-the-sorting-arrows/p1 do fórum do datatables você pode tentar (além do stop propagation) é dar unbind no event listener adicionado na inicialização do DT e depois adicionar o fnSortListener manualmente e escolher uma div que vai ordenar o texto e deixar a checbox fora dessa div. Mas eu nunca tentei isso e também não sei dizer se o datables vai saber ordenar por selecionado e não selecionado.

Comment: Sem problemas @Rafael . Ainda não vi esse no fórum, vou dar uma olhada. Valew